# What does $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

What does $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ mean? I mean I cannot picture it in any way. I found it in an algebra problem and it's bugging me.

Comment: Do you want to explain what $R$ is first?

Comment: The set of real numbers.

Comment: There is a function defined on this set and i don't know how it could look like

Comment: In general $A^B$ is the set of all functions $B\to A$.

Comment: Generally, $Y^{X}$ is the set of all functions from $X$ to $Y$.  Thus, in your problem $R^R$ is the set of all functions from $R$ to $R$; i.e., the set of all real-valued functions defined on the real line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are sets, $A^B$ is sometimes used to denote the set of functions with domain $B$ and range $A$. So $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ is the set of functions over the real numbers.

Comment: One should add that the reason for this notation is that if $|A|$ is the number of members of $A$ and $B$ is the number of members of $B$ then $|A|^{|B|}$ is the number of members of $A^B$. In other words, it makes $|A|^{|B|}$ equal to $\left| A^B \right|. \qquad$